# How to change cardview background color Programmatically in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-cardview

I try to do this:

`cardview.cardBackgroundColor(Color)`

but I have this message: The function 'invoke()' is not found.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, I forgot the `set`

`cardview.setCardBackgroundColor(Color)`

Everything works fine now, the background of my `cardview` change.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried using

```
cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

or create any color from a reference like below

```
 val color = ContextCompat.getColor(this@SplashActivity, R.color.colorPrimary)
 cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(color);
```